# Excel worksheet.name with two cell value criteria

Tags: vba, excel

My issue today is trying to get a new worksheet name to have two different cell.values when being named.

The current code takes the data from one tab and creates different worksheets based on what is in cell range K7. So each tab is populated with the data based on the K7 column. Currently I have the new worksheet names set at

```
wsnew.name = "NIIN " + cell.value
```

Which does its job and brings back tabs labeled "NIIN xxxxxxxx" .

I also have another column titled 'Sample' with range starting at A7.

The values for this column are all the same if it has the same K7 values.

Is there a way to get VBA to find the cell value from both A7 and K7 and add it the worksheet name?

Ideally I would like it to be something like this

```
wsnew.name = "Sample " + cell.value (a7 range) + " NIIN " + cell.value (k7 range)
```

---

Adding the code provided gives me worksheet names such as "Sample xxxxxx NIIN   "

The xxxxx should actually be infront of the NIIN so that it reads "Sample..... NIIN xxxxxx"

```
WSNew.Name = "Sample " & cell.Offset(0, 10).Value  & " NIIN " &  cell.Value
```

This is the code i added and it switched the format to "Sample    NIIN xxxxxx"

Which works well however i am still not getting the value after Sample.

I have tried the `cell.offset (O,-10).value` however that gives me an error

---

The code below is what comes before the worksheet naming

```
Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add

    With ws2
        'first we copy the Unique data from the filter field to ws2
        My_Table.ListColumns(FieldNum).Range.AdvancedFilter _
                Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                CopyToRange:=.Range("A1"), Unique:=True

        'loop through the unique list in ws2 and filter/copy to a new sheet
        Lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cell In .Range("A2:A" & Lrow)

            'Filter the range
            My_Table.Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:="=" & _
                                                                  Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "~", "~~"), "*", "~*"), "?", "~?")

            CCount = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            CCount = My_Table.ListColumns(1).Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(1).Cells.Count
            On Error GoTo 0

            If CCount = 0 Then
                MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas for the value : " & cell.Value _
                     & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data to a new worksheet." _
                     & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
                       vbOKOnly, "Split in worksheets"
```

---

[Original sheet with the data and micro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Mrk.png)

[What the code does when cell.value comes after & " NIIN "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqi2Z.png)

I hope these pictures help with the question.

As you can see from the pictures when the macro is clicked, it creates many sheets based on the criteria in K7 which is the NIIN field.

As you can also see the value under EY Sample is what i want in the output after "Sample..."

So that it reads (for example) "Sample 5 NIIN 1212"

---

This is the entire code. I am sure there is a much better way to have written it out. I used  the basic knowledge and experience that i have. Many apologies for the headache this is creating

```
Sub Copy_To_Worksheets()
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim WSNew As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim FieldNum As Long
Dim My_Table As ListObject
Dim ErrNum As Long
Dim ActiveCellInTable As Boolean
Dim CCount As Long

'Select a cell in the column that you want to filter in the List or Table

Application.GoTo Sheets("SplitInWorksheets").Range("K7")

If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = True Then
MsgBox "This macro is not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
           vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set rng = ActiveCell

'Test if rng is in a a list or Table
On Error Resume Next
ActiveCellInTable = (rng.ListObject.Name <> "")
On Error GoTo 0

'If the cell is in a List or Table run the code
If ActiveCellInTable = True Then

    Set My_Table = rng.ListObject
    FieldNum = rng.Column - My_Table.Range.Cells(1).Column + 1

    'Show all data in the Table/List
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    ' Add a worksheet to copy the a unique list and add the CriteriaRange
    Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add

    With ws2
        'first we copy the Unique data from the filter field to ws2
        My_Table.ListColumns(FieldNum).Range.AdvancedFilter _
                Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                CopyToRange:=.Range("A1"), Unique:=True




  'loop through the unique list in ws2 and filter/copy to a new sheet
        Lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cell In .Range("A2:A" & Lrow)

            'Filter the range
            My_Table.Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:="=" & _
                                                                  Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "~", "~~"), "*", "~*"), "?", "~?")

            CCount = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            CCount = My_Table.ListColumns(1).Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(1).Cells.Count
            On Error GoTo 0

            If CCount = 0 Then
                MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas for the value : " & cell.Value _
                     & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data to a new worksheet." _
                     & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
                       vbOKOnly, "Split in worksheets"
            Else
                Set WSNew = Worksheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
                On Error Resume Next
                WSNew.Name = "Sample " & cell.Offset(0, 10).Value & " NIIN " & cell.Value

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    ErrNum = ErrNum + 1
                    WSNew.Name = "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000")
                    Err.Clear
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                'Copy the visible data and use PasteSpecial to paste to the new worksheet
                My_Table.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                With WSNew.Range("A1")
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    .Select
                End With
            End If

            'Show all data in the Table/List
            My_Table.Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum

        Next cell

       'Delete the ws2 sheet
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        On Error GoTo 0



    End With

    If ErrNum > 0 Then MsgBox "Rename every WorkSheet name that start with ""Error_"" manually" & vbNewLine & _
       "There are characters in the Unique name that are not allowed in a sheet name or the sheet exist."

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "Select a cell in the column of the List or Table that you want to  filter"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot follow what exactly you want. You need to use more than just "xxxxx" to show what data is supposed to be where.

Comment: you're asking me to concatenate 4 values: `sample + a7 + NIIN + 
k7` but you are only specifying three things in  your expected output `"Sample NIIN xxxxxx"` so it's really hard to understand what your problem actually is

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 My apologies. the expected output should be  "Sample (cell value in A7) NIIN (Cell value in K7)" So it should read something like "Sample 1 NIIN 1234567"

Comment: so when the code i provided doesn't work, instead of getting (for example) "Sample A NIIN 1234567", you're only getting "Sample NIIN 1234567" ?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 That is correct. I double checked to see if there are any empty cells and that is not the case.

Comment: well in your comment you do say that your data starts at A7 but your code says `For Each cell In .Range("A2:A" & Lrow)` which starts at A2

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 is there a way i can send you the excel file ? i dont believe i am communicating well. Or is there a way i can upload a video to my question to show what i want the code to do?

Comment: the easiest way is to mock up some data that matches yours at least in format and upload a picture of it as an edit to your question

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 There are two pictures provided One showing the original sheet and another showing what the macro does.

Comment: I'm really not completely sure what the hangup is. I imagine that at this point it is a problem with the ordering of the code. You loop through each cell on the worksheet and each time you rename the worksheet itself. There's likely a better place/way to do that

Comment: I would recommend opening the code module, clicking "View Locals" and using [F8] to step through each line of the code and seeing when the sheets get renamed so you can see what the values are that you're trying assign as the sheet name

Comment: perhaps we should move the name assignment above the `For Each cell...` line and just base the sheet name on the values in A2 and K2

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 After running the code module with F8 this is what occurs.
1. Code goes to the main worksheet and looks at Range ("K7")
2. It then copies the column into another worksheet that is used to filter out the data from the main sheet
3. When new worksheets are created it uses the cell value from the temporary worksheet created for filtering
4. The temp worksheet is then deleted after all items within the filter list are looped
The temp table references A2 because there is no other cell value present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA you concatenate strings with the `&` character. Second, to access column K when you're looping through column A, you can just do a simple `.Offset(row,col)`.

So your line of code becomes:

```
WSNew.Name = "Sample " & cell.Value & " NIIN " & cell.Offset(0,10).Value
'SheetName =  Sample   +     A7     +   NIIN   +          K7
```

Comment: Hello @Marcucciboy2 Thank you for the help. I added the code and just switched the cell values around so that sample had the offsetvalue and NIIN had the cell.value.  When the worksheets are created i am getting " Sample     NIIN xxxxxxx" It should say something along " Sample xx NIIN xxxxxx". Is there something i am doing wrong with the offset?

Comment: there is no reason for the code to behave like you say if you do exactly what the answer says. Maybe update your question with the code that is generating Sample NIIN xxxxxxx

Comment: From your update I can assume that a valid explanation is that cell is an empty cell. Without the inputs it's hard to tell

Comment: @ChristianCapoPerez when you say you want your answer to actually be `Sample xx NIIN xxxxxx`, does that mean that you want the first two characters of cell K7 before "NIIN" followed by the last 6 characters of cell K7?

Comment: @GerardoFlores After checking the cells, that is correct. The value that i am looking for is 10 spaces to the left. I have used the -10 to see if that would work and it defaults to my error statement.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 that is not what i am looking for. In my worksheet i have a value in A7. That value is what i am looking for after "Sample" followed by "NIIN" and K7 cell value. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 If it helps, the code for the macro takes the data from the sheet and filters it first by range ("k7") From there it is put into a temp worksheet. the worksheet takes the unique data from the filter and loops through each unique list which then creates the individual worksheets.